# What does firefox do differently when interacting with a website in mobile mode?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, mobile, browser

I am trying to track down a bug that only occurs on mobile devices (and on Firefox in mobile mode).
When I switch to Firefox mobile mode (using CTRL+SHIFT+M), the bug is immediately reproduceable (without needing to manually reload the page). At first I thought it was a CSS issue, but it seems that there may be some JavaScript at work.

If I can identify what Firefox does differently when in mobile mode, I may be able to better isolate the problem or create a hackish solution, so my question is **what does Firefox do differently when interacting with a website in mobile mode?**

From my understanding, Firefox in mobile mode

- changes the User Agent
- and it spoofs media queries such as the size of the screen and the
  pixel density.
- It doesn't seem to reload the page (although it does seems to
  rerequest the favicon of the page I am testing).
- It could trigger an onresize event when switching between modes.

  Based on the above information, the User Agent is unlikely to be causing the bug that I am seeing.
  CSS could be a factor.
  JavaScript might be doing something on detecting the onresize event.

**Does Firefox mobile mode do anything else that I have missed?**

Comment: It's a bit like fishing in muddy waters - what is the bug you're talking about?

Comment: I've reworded the question a little because what I am really trying to get out of this question is "what does firefox do in mobile mode?" Based on that information I can try and debug it myself. The bug/issue is complicated and I think discussing it will detract from the question at hand.